# How do you get a BitBucket pull request to trigger a Bamboo build?

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo, pull-request, continuous-delivery

I'm working on CI/CD environment for my workplace. One of the issues we're struggling with is the pull request workflow we currently use, and which we want to continue to use.

We can get BitBucket to tell Bamboo to make a build when you commit to a feature branch and push it to BitBucket, but for the life of me I can't find anything in there related to actual pull requests. In our instance, it would be great if a plan branch would be created when a pull request for a feature branch is generated in BitBucket. Subsequent commits would then trigger additional builds on the PR plan branch. Is this even possible on Bamboo with BitBucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating this to say that proper pull request support was finally added to Bamboo in version 6.0:
[release notes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-6-0-release-notes-894743804.html)
You can now configure the plan branching model to automatically create branches when new PRs are added to Bitbucket.

Comment: Since this is actually a viable answer now, I'll accept this one. Good job Atlassian.

Comment: I need to create the plan branch already when the branch is created. How do I trigger now a build in case a PR is created?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somebody answered your question on another forum: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/17435563/how-do-you-get-a-bitbucket-pull-request-to-trigger-a-bamboo-build which references this feature request for Bamboo: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14844

I'm posting this here for other people like myself who stumble across this question.

Answer (score 0):

The bamboo feature called plan branches has been implemented in recent releases. See the link posted by Mynock, or [directly here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-plan-branches-289276872.html).